# Pattern for random subsetting with domains in Chapel

Tags: chapel

Here is my set up.  In hockey, players form into "lines" which are on the ice at the same time.  A "forward" line is a trio of Left Wing, Center and Right Wing.  A "D" line is a pair of Left D and Right D.  In beer leagues, you typically dress 13 skaters = 3 Forward lines, 2 D lines plus one Goalie.

Suppose I have 20 people who want to play.  I want to construct the lines from 13 random skaters.  I have to preserve their names and jersey numbers.  I'm wondering if this is the job of [Chapel Domains](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/1.15/primers/domains.html).  For instance, something like

```
var player_ids: domain(1) = {1..20}
var jerseys [player_ids] = [71, 99, 97, ...]
var names [player_ids] = ['Alice', 'Bonobo', 'Changarakoo'...]
```

It's a simple idea, but now I want to

```
1. Pick three random players and assign them to Line 1 F
2. Pick three from the remainders and assign the to Line 2 F
...
n-1: Use the player ids to create an indicator matrix (details aren't important)
n: WIN!
```

The point of `n-1` is that I have to be able to reference the player id and jersey number at the end.

What is the correct pattern for this in Chapel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. To draw players without replacement, I conceptually think of *shuffling* a deck of cards - where each card has a player's name on it. So this code uses [Random.shuffle](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/modules/standard/Random.html#Random.shuffle).

```
use Random;

var player_ids = {1..20};
// jersey number, name are simply keyed off off player_id

// Generate an array of player IDs
var ids_array = [i in player_ids] i;

// Randomly shuffle player IDs
shuffle(ids_array);

// Now select from the shuffled IDs the players for the game.

var cur = 1;
getLine(cur, "Forward1", 3, ids_array);
getLine(cur, "Forward2", 3, ids_array);
getLine(cur, "Forward3", 3, ids_array);
getLine(cur, "D1", 2, ids_array);
getLine(cur, "D2", 2, ids_array);
getLine(cur, "Goalie", 1, ids_array);

proc getLine(ref curIndex, lineName, playersNeeded, ids_array) {
  writeln("Line ", lineName, ":");
  for i in 1..playersNeeded {
    writeln("  player ", ids_array[curIndex]); // would use name & jersey..
    curIndex += 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: The shuffle technique is my go-to method, but I over-complicated it by trying use domains. I just wasn't sure if there was an efficiency to be gained somehow by using them.  Thanks to both mppf and @user3666197

Comment: Note that in @mppf's solution, you'd use `ids_array` as an indirect index into your original `jerseys` and `names` array.  Thus, your solution would likely have expressions like `jerseys[ids_array[i]]` and `names[ids_array[i]]` in them.  Another approach that avoids this permutation vector could (a) create a "player" type that stored name, jersey #, whatever, (b) create an array of players instead of an array of player_ids, (c) shuffle that array of players directly.

Comment: With all due respect to the possible syntax used, in regulated business-domains, it is common to knowingly separate records with private data from all of the other processing. In such controlled-environments, there would always be a need to prove a robustness of a referential integrity ( between a private person ( or a legally protected entity in general ) and GUIID#hash, that can be freely used in data-processing workflows & derived reports ). For this reason an "easy" indirection need not be a way to go for such reasons. A split dStore + a robust enough pub_key:priv_data mechanics are needed

Answer (score 2):

### The Beer-Hockey Team Coach
 can use this concept
also
[`( live >>> online )` <sub>( sure, numbers will vary, no fixed RNG-seed was set )</sub>](https://tio.run/##rZBLawJBEITv8yuKzSVCRx3NexNB0DwOhqDJSURGd0yGrDPLPiIi/vZNz@YQhUASSMMcmq7p@qrnryrRcVkWmcZQ2cgtQyHeVYq9Up@jp353gGuMIQktQptwTDghnBLOCOeEC4Js8uO5ZIFkhWSJZI1kkWSVZJlkXauJSYhGAwpv1q0sYe5sbl4KV2ToPzwP4Ba4UtbZ9dJkOpredUd30/veQdYRHinR6bLIVW6cPdzjq4X4v9rly7zbHIPuo0fbtTzq4GYaG6s3sl5vbwm9qpO@bXF7SxjqLBdi4dK/uJsIxsJvke3tpoq9Sk2uY44cKIy@gBKXGX8KT@aRxgHxb0IwucTKxDFmGkms1jrCbI1vrsoLSfzEs5N5XOFN6NdZAtSCfYNaWPVbUZYf)

Let's go a bit deeper into the process. The randomised selection is the mathematically harder part of the story ( where compliance will complicate the issues more in domains outside the skating ring, than for the Coach himself (ref. below ) ).

So, let's accept that the Team setup is a static-map, where players' ordinals map onto the `F_line{1..3,1..3}, D_line{1..2,1..2}, G, Rest{1..7}`

```
use Random;
var              aRandomTEAM = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]; // a known, contiguous ENUM of <anonymised_HASH_ID#s>
    permutation( aRandomTEAM );                                                                           // a known, static MAP of aRandomTEAM -> F_line{1..3}, D_line1{1..2}, G, Rest
for                          id in {1..13}{
    writeln(                   "            a Static MAP position of TEAM[",
                             id, "]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( ",
                 aRandomTEAM[id],                                         " )"
             );
    }
```

### For human-readable inspection, this produces:

```
a Static MAP position of TEAM[1]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 20 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[2]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 5 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[3]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 11 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[4]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 4 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[5]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 15 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[6]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 7 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[7]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 16 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[8]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 12 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[9]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 8 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[10]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 18 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[11]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 19 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[12]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 17 )
a Static MAP position of TEAM[13]: will be played by anonymised_HASH_ID#( 3 )
```

hovever, the machine-readable post-processing may map these onto requested arrays, keep the sensitive personal details safe and separate, having the GUUID#-reference links into names and all other details safe. The referential integrity is both cheap and safe and an implementation of static unique associative mapping from ( intentionally ) contiguous ordinals onto a proxy-anonymising HashTable is trivial ( ref. Opaque Domains and Arrays for possible further inspirations ).

---

### Legal Warning:

A due care ought be taken if using a randomisation in regulated domains, where a compliance has to be documented and positive proofs of methods' robustness performed and validated.

Documentation may bring more details on known risks for using the current randomisation implementations in some legally demanding domains:

> **Permuted Linear Congruential Random Number Generator**
>
> This module provides PCG random number generation routines. See http://www.pcg-random.org/ and the paper, PCG: A Family of Simple Fast Space-Efficient Statistically Good Algorithms for Random Number Generation by M.E. O'Neill.

Of a particular attention ought be some known potential restrictions, like:

> **Note**
>
> For integers, this class uses a strategy for generating a value in a particular range that has not been subject to rigorous study and may have statistical problems.
>
> For real numbers, this class generates a random value in [max, min] by computing a random value in [0,1] and scaling and shifting that value. Note that not all possible floating point values in the interval [min, max] can be constructed in this way.

Remarks like this should always attract due attention of Compliance Officers, so as to carefully pre-validate a feasibility of use within their intended ( regulated ) problem-domain mandatory practices and controlled-environments' requirements.

Comment: Luckily, beer league hockey can't afford compliance officers.  Thanks for the `permutation` function.  It wasn't clear from this answer that the permutation occurs in place.

Comment: Can't aford to have the Beer Compliance Officer? Well, never mind, then just the **Beer Officer** *will be enough to fix it* Glad you enjoy the [Chapel] powers ... will be cool on realistic scales of the samples to get randomised -- anyway, a lovely narrative with a team setup  :o)

Comment: Note that Random.permutation doesn't actually use the contents of the array. I.e. the aRandomTeam array could have been initialized with 20 zeros and it would produce the same result.

Comment: Interesting. Is this principal behaviour somewhere documented? The specification I have read was not explicitly mentioning such cardinal side-effect.